# Resolving MVC chaos

Tags: ios, objective-c

The following is my setup:

- `Controller` (.h/.m)
- `ConnectionManager` (.h/.m) - Sends Requests using AFNetworking
- `RequestHandler` (.h/.m) - Build Request Params
- `KeyManager` (.h/.m) - Writes to database

I have to send a request to server with some data from KeyManager.

Here the request is sent using AFNetworking in `ConnectionManager`. All the request parameters and URL for request is constructed by `RequestHandler`

but problem is in order to construct the request I have some data requested from controller and I when initialize the `Controller` inside `RequestHandlers` it throws error Controller type can't be found

`Controller` -> `ConnectionManager` -> `RequestHandler` -> `Controller` -> `ConnectionManager` -> **Server**

How can I resolve this? Also, how do I pass the current instance of class to the new instance of another class?

Comment: Use `@class` in your headers instead of `#import`

Comment: why don't you just make your controller a singelton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option to resolve these kind of circular definitions is to use `#import` directives in the `.m` files only and instead use `@class` in the `.h` files.

So basically if you need a reference to class X in the API for class Y, then in Y.h, you add `@class X`, then in `Y.m`, you add `#import X`

`@class` simply defines the symbol. Basically tells the compiler "trust me, I'll tell you what this is later". Then you hold true to the promise by using `#import` in the implementation of that class.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: This seems to the solution and a better way to do it. Thanks, but can you tell me is singleton a bad approach as @abbood pointed?

Answer (score 1):

The general problem of a class needing an instance of another class can be solved using the [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) pattern

In short if you need access to an instance of an object, give it to the dependent object when you create it.

For your RequestHandler you might construct an init method like this.

```
-(instance_type)initWithController:(Controller *)acontroller
{
self = [super init];
if(self)
{
    _controller = acontroller;
}
return self;

}
```

or alternatively a method on the instance

```
-(void)setupHandlerWithController:(Controller *)acontroller
{
//do what you need to do to setup
}
```

either way means you are giving the RequestHandler the thing that it needs rather than trying to create a **Controller** instance for the purpose of setting up the **RequestHandler**

The **ConnectionManager** thats creating the **RequestHandler** will probably already need the  **Controller** handed to it so it can give it to the **RequestHandler**

TBH Id be looking at *why* the RequestHandler needs access to the **Controller** and attempt to factor that out.

Exactly what does the **RequestHandler** need from the **Controller** and can it be given those things directly.

This will mean you can use the **RequestHandler** in multiple places if you want to simply by giving it the things it needs.

Comment: I will have to follow mprivat solution to use your answer I think because the _controller can't be created otherwise.